Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Boots to white screen. All this happened when I Switch everything on on accessibility settings
after doing some accessibility settings in ubuntu 24.04 LTS my laptop screen turned bright and white.as were the settings. I have my screen reader turned on but how to use it to go back to initial good looking settings.

You may need to use terminal to restore your settings back to the defaults. this article may be of some help.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I'm glad to hear that you resolved your issue. Since it went away after a complete reinstall, there's really no way for us to know what the root cause or solution was, so I've voted to close the question since it won't be helpful to others in the future.

I formatted my laptop by booting using bootable Ubuntu 24.04 pendrive. The laptop is working fine now.
